# Shapefile appears correct on QGIS, but wrong on Google Earth

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, datum

I've created a shapefile on QGIS, drawing over a raster that I've just georeferenced. The raster is a map with UTM lines drawn every 50 meters, so it was easy to georeference. Moving the mouse over it shows that the coordinates are accurate. The shapefile created also appears correct. (That's when the Project Properties' CRS is SAD69 / UTM zone 23S = EPSG:29193 -- for lat 20°S and lon 44°W -- so that I can see the coordinates in meters. The CRS of the shapefile drawn is WGS 84 = EPSG:4326, which automatically adjusts to the project, since 'on the fly' CRS transformation is allowed.)

When I open the same shapefile on Google Earth, I see it's shifted 50 meters to the West, when the difference between the Google Earth imagery and the map I used is just about 6 meters. What may be going on?

EDIT

The shapefile: https://www.sendspace.com/file/u22o3j

(Forgot to add a .prj file -- probably the source of all this). It contains:

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

I did reproject (save vector layer as...) to SIRGAS 2000 (EPSG:31983), but got the same error. Tried to EPSG:29193, and now there's an error in another direction (north-nortwest, instead of west).

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: This sounds like maybe on the fly projection isn't working as desired. Have you tried creating the shapefile in the EPSG:29193 instead of EPSG:4326?

Comment: @Erik I can upload the shapefile in question, but where?

Comment: Whereever floats your goat... data.

Comment: @ycartwhelen Do you mean draw it all over again, or just reproject? I did reproject (save vector layer as...) to SIRGAS 2000 (EPSG:31983), but got the same error. Tried to EPSG:29193, and now there's an error in another direction (north-nortwest, instead of west).

Comment: @Erik https://www.sendspace.com/file/u22o3j

Comment: Please include the data (and additional information) in your post, not everyone is fond of scouring the comments for extra snippets.

Comment: @Rodrigo I was meaning if possible work entirely in one projection, so in this case probably redrawing the shapefile if reprojecting keeps being off.

Comment: QGIS sometimes stores projection information in a non-standard format that other programs don't understand. When you open the shapefile in Google Earth, are you sure that Google Earth understands what projection it's in?

Comment: @csk How can I be sure? I'm not. I've opened the shapefile in R, and it's being read exactly as in Google Earth.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Earth, but it should have a way to check the layer's CRS. Is there a way to check the layer properties?

Comment: @csk no CRS in Google Earth, as far as I know.